# How is the callback function passed in aws lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am new to aws-lambda, please explain with example if possible.

Also, in the documentation, what does it mean by:

> callback – You can use the optional callback to return information to
>   the caller, otherwise return value is null

Who is the caller? I thought lambda functions are automatically called in response to events

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda is not only called by automatic events. You can invoke Lambda functions directly via the AWS API/SDK/CLI and wait for a response. You can also place an AWS API Gateway in front of a Lambda function which would then use the response from the Lambda function to generate the API response.

Your other question regarding the callback function, which is specific to NodeJS AWS Lambda functions, is a bit vague. The callback function is one of the parameters of your NodeJS AWS Lambda function. It is passed to your Lambda function handler as a parameter. This should be obvious from looking at [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html), on the same page where you copied that quote from.